# navigation icon here maps is missing during Turn by Turn Navigation in HERE SDK

Tags: here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

When the application is opened, sometimes the pointer will be displayed and sometimes not.
In the case where a pointer is displayed , when we navigate to another screen (Activity/Fragment) and come back to the Map screen, the pointer will disappear. No error is traced in logcat

Here SDK used - heresdk-navigate-android-4.9.4.0.7265[Navigation Pointer (Arrow) missing in turn by turn navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxPB7.jpg)

Comment: also in Flutter same

Answer (score 0):

When you switch MapViews, make sure to resume them. Also, you need to add/remove the `LocationIndicator` yourself. During navigation you can swap the `MapView` instance (if needed):

```
public void swapMapView(MapView newMapView) {
    if (isVisualNavigatorRenderingStarted) {
        visualNavigator.stopRendering();
        mapView = newMapView;
        customLocationIndicator.enable(mapView);
        customLocationIndicator.setLocationIndicatorStyle(LocationIndicator.IndicatorStyle.NAVIGATION);
        visualNavigator.setCustomLocationIndicator(customLocationIndicator);
        visualNavigator.startRendering(mapView);
    } else {
        this.mapView = newMapView;
    }
}
```

Make sure to set the indicator also to the `VisualNavigator`.

There is an example app that shows how to use custom location indicators:
https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/android/NavigationCustom